# Get compressed X9.62 encoded EC public key in Java

Tags: java

I have a public-private KeyPair generated with this code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(256, secureRandom);
KeyPair pair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

I'd like to get a byte array representing the public key, encoded using X9.62 **with** point compression:

> ANSI X9.62 defines a mandatory octet string representation for elliptic points in either compressed, uncompressed, or hybrid form

My basic understanding of point compression is that it enables the other end to figure out (using the curve) the Y co-ordinate from the point represented by the public key, given only the X co-ordinate and the LSB of the Y co-ordinate in the start byte (0x02 or 0x03). I can get the two `BigInteger` X and Y values as follows:

```
ECPoint point = ((ECPublicKey) pk.getPublic()).getW();
BigInteger y = point.getAffineY();
BigInteger x = point.getAffineX();
```

How would I go about encoding the public key information into a byte array, using the compressed form in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X9.62 compressed and uncompressed (but not hybrid) forms are more conveniently specified in SEC1 at http://www.secg.org
and there is a (nonJava) example at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63876/can-any-ecc-field-element-be-safely-serialized-as-compressed-and-then-restored .

If you want this encoded publickey to be read by practically any other software, including standard Java crypto,
you need not only the X9.62/SEC1 encoding, but that encoding wrapped either in a full **X.509 certificate,
or at least the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI)`** structure defined by X.509. SPKI wraps the algorithm-dependent key data
(for ECC X9.62, for other algorithms other things) in an ASN.1 SEQUENCE with an `AlgorithmIdentifier` which
identifies the algorithm (easy enough) plus where applicable the parameters, which for ECC is the curve,
almost always in "named" form using a (standardized) ASN.1 OID that identifies the curve.
Any Java `PublicKey.getEncoded()` including `ECPublicKey` returns,
and all `KeyFactory.generatePublic()` accept, an encoding Java names "X.509" which is actually SPKI.

OpenSSL can use either SPKI (which it calls PUBKEY on the API, and `PUBLIC KEY` in PEM delimiters) or certificate.
Much other software accepts only a cert, or a PKCS#12 aka PFX that combines the cert with the privatekey. SSH, including I believe OpenSSH though
I don't have a new enough version yet to test, does accept SEC1/X9.62 with just a XDRish string to identifiy both algorithm and curve.

The `KeyPair` from an EC generator initialized with an integer size as you did actually uses a named curve,
but the API for `ECParameterSpec` returned by `EC{Public,Private}Key.getParams()` can't get its OID.
You can get the underlying field, coefficients, basepoint etc and encode in explicit form, but (1) that wastes a lot of space, many times more than
you save by compressing the publickey point and (2) other software may not accept/support it.
You should either

- use `ECPublicKey.getEncoded()` to get SPKI including the AlgId, parse the point from the algorithm-dependent part (which is trivial),
  reencode the point, and rebuild the structure; or
- go the other direction by generating a key *on a specified curve* by `.initialize` with `ECGenParameterSpec(name)`
  then encode the known curve (and fixed algorithm) with the resulting public point.

Either way see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480 and if you like the earlier https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279.html about SPKI for ECC.

Comment: The server I'm using this with only works with the NID_X9_62_prime256v1 curve - it therefore becomes unnecessary to explicitly include the curve name/parameters along with the actual co-ordinates in this particular case. Interoperability isn't important to me, since there's only one server-side implementation of this authentication scheme.

If you take a look at https://github.com/kaniini/ecdsatool/blob/master/libecdsaauth/keypair.c#L73 you'll see the curve type is set when the key is allocated, along with an explicit X9.62 form of 'compressed'.